# A dynamic calendar Tab bar icon that changes to the actual date

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, icons

Is there a way to make one as i have seen one on the istudiez pro app and was wondering how you would do it. This is what I have so far but the text test is not displayed. Not sure why?

```
@implementation TabBarIcon

CGContextRef CGBitmapContextCreate (
void *data,
size_t width,
size_t height,
size_t bitsPerComponent,
size_t bytesPerRow,
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace,
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo
);

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)Rect{   

CGImageRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextStroke);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 12.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, transform);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 100.0, 100.0, "test", strlen("test"));
}
```

CGImageRef CGBitmapContextCreateImage(CGContextRef context);

@end

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with istudiez pro, but it sounds like it's just a matter of assigning a different tab bar image depending on the date; you haven't mentioned whether you're targeting iOS or OSX, but for the former you create an instance of UITabBarItem created with the appropriate image and assign it to the appropriate UIViewController's `tabBarItem`.

If it's just "day of the month" you could include all 31 possible images, otherwise you can use Core Graphics to draw the appropriate image at runtime.

Comment: thanks yh i am developing for ios and it's gonna be day and month so i am thinking the second way will be easier except i haven't really used core graphics at all yet.

Comment: It's not too difficult. Create a [CGBitmapContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html), then use the [CGContext functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) to do the actual drawing, and then `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` to get the image out.

Comment: Or you could use [UIKit's graphics functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html), which are somewhat less powerful but may be easier to use.

Comment: i have learnt how to use core graphics i just need help with creating an instance of UITabBarItem as it's not working out right.

Comment: @Dangermouse: Use [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006928-CH3-SW3).

Comment: i've updated my question not sure why it is not working and i know i have to replace data, width and height stuff but not sure with what as i just want to display a number now.

Comment: You should probably post that as a new question instead. And include more context (e.g. what isTabBarIcon supposed to be a subclass of? How are you trying to use it along with a tab bar?), as it is that code is so far from anything that would work that I'm not sure where to begin.